Are there any plans to do old community events soon/in the future?
In the past, we've done multiple community events (well... you all did. I wasn't here yet).

Movie night
Marathons
Giveaways
Among Us (oh no the meme game)

and whatever else I missed.
I'm aware most coordinators aren't here anymore (Yuuki and LoveAndCoding have both been inactive for more than a year, for example), but they sound fun.
Are there any plans to do something similar soon/in the future?

I wasn't even aware we used to have giveaways

I don't think there are any plans, at least among us moderators - but there is nothing stopping you - the Community!
Community events can be created by anyone if they so choose to.  We do have a Discord that you are welcome to use as well. As of right now, Screenshot of the Week is the only community event that we've been running (for quite a while now actually).
I joined the site at a time where I think these community events (at least movie nights) were on the decline, so I don't have much insight about them or how they were organized.  The giveaways event actually seemed to have been sponsored by Stack Exchange (seems like SE Staff was in charge of that one looking at that linked post).  I don't think we could bring something like that back.

The giveaways were done by SE, and as far as I'm aware, they have no intention of ever bringing them back.

Aww…. You mean SE isn’t going to feed our gamer addictions fun?
